# Will an asynctask crash an app if it redefines a variable inside doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this line of code

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            //unnecessary geocoder calculations

               strReturnedAddress = (returnedAddress.getLocality().toString());
        }
                }
            }


        return null;
    }
```

It used to work for the past 2 days but today, for some reason, my application keeps crashing and logcat is showing this line as the error's source. When I delete this line the application does not crash.

Should I instead create a new string and return it from the doInBackground method and set strReturnedAddress in onPostExecute? I am really clueless because this worked just yesterday night.

Edit: Here is the logcat

```
   07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027):    at com.example.realapptest1.MainActivity$GetCurrentCity.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:407)
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027):    at com.example.realapptest1.MainActivity$GetCurrentCity.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-13 16:43:57.480: E/AndroidRuntime(28027):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: What is error saying?

Comment: what type of variable is strReturnedAddress? Are you passing any varibales in Async.execute() ?

Comment: strReturnedAddress is a globally declared string. no variables are passed in async.execute()

Comment: Dude, what is the error?

Comment: i just reimplemented the code to get the logcat. i have edited the original post and included the logcat.

Comment: OK, the problem is that returnedAddress is null or returnedAddress.getLocality() is null. It does not have anything to do with you global string variable.

Comment: p.s. = line 407 is `strReturnedAddress = (returnedAddress.getLocality().toString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely set values on doInBackground as long as they aren't any UI elements (e.g. textView.setText, etc.) as these changes are supposed to run on the UI thread.
The exception you see simply means that either returnedAddress is null or returnedAddress.getLocality() returns null...
Debug your code to better understand the problem you're facing

Comment: You do need proper synchronization or the code may fail, unexpectedly, without the ability to reproduce or debug. Don't do this. use onPostExecute or onProgressUpdate

Comment: i dont know why this was downvoted. that is exactly what i needed. the string is a global string, nothing UI related.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `returnedAddress` variable, you can handle result like this:

```
strReturnedAddress = returnedAddress == null || returnedAddress.getLocality() == null ? 
                     "Not Found" : returnedAddress.getLocality().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem should be that in

```
returnedAddress.getLocality().toString();
```

is used a null variable shomewhere.

However you should be careful if you're using `strReturnedAddress` in the UI Thread somewhere. doInBackground doesn't execute on the UI Thread but in a WorkerThread as you can see from the logcat.

As said in a comment, you should use `onPostExecution` (or `onPreExecution`,`onProgressUpdate`) to update variables shared with the UI Thread, since the code you put inside them will run in the UIThread. Otherwise you can use synchronized/volatile.

I want also advise you to pay attention with AsyncTask since it may not execute depending on the current state of the JVM and the calling Activity.